# Vim: delete all but the current line

Tags: vim

I know this is a bit of vim-golfing, but I am interested in other opinions / ideas. Sometimes I have to edit a file and to delete all but the current line. My go to solution involves ex mode `:t0|2,$d`

These are as many as 8 keystrokes! (I am aware that this command can be mapped easily to some convenient combination on the keyboard.) Other suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all your approach is not 8 keystrokes, if we don't count the save (`ZZ`), they are 9 keystrokes. Because you have to press `Enter`.

There is one way, with 6 keystrokes:

```
YggVGp
```

Apart from golfing, I feel my approach is more straightforward than yours. Perhaps because I like normal mode in vim. :-)

For practice, if you need do it many times, you may want to have a mapping.

Comment: A 33.33% improvement and normal mode. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
:.w!|e<CR>
```

Comment: What might matter is that the file is effectively changed while OP's original solution just changed the buffer. It depends on the use case but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Your solution makes me smile :) Just as a sidenote: There are two assumptions though. It assumes (1) a filename and (2) a saved buffer - (1) is not always the case (at least for my use cases, e.g. output of a shell command), (2) unsaved buffers may need a `:.w!|e!<cr>` - 8 keystrokes (including the <cr> - which I forgot to count ;) ) . For saved files almost (+1 keystroke) as good as Kent's normal mode solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, there are *lots* of assumption in my answer.